# Need suggestion on the selection of rechargeable battery

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am planning on to design a system to power my router. Unfortunately, there are shortcomings of electricity in our area and I want my router to operate 24/7.
I have read the specs of the router and it requires **12v/1A | 12watts**.

What I want to do now is to select a **Small size rechargeable battery** so that I can power my router through it when my main electric power is cut-off. I thought about **3v7 LI-ION** battery with a *Boost converter* but LI-ION can't provide me, ideally about 3.4A (12w/3v7) continuously. So should I connect two LI-ION in series (3.7x2) to drive *Boost  converter* i.e (12/7v4 = 1.62A) or there is another better approach which can be both cost-efficient and suitable for the above purpose?

Comment: The first step is to figure out how many Watt hours (Wh) you need. If you want to keep the router alive for 10 hours, then you need 10 hours * 12 Watts / 80% efficiency = 150 Wh. This would not be a "small size rechargeable battery." So how long DO you want to keep it alive for?

Comment: @mkeith: Thanks for the reply, i forgot to mention that one. I need at least 52Wh. It should be alive for 3.5 hours.

Comment: If you only need 12V DC I'd be inclined to go for the simpler option and use a 12V sealed lead acid battery rather than requiring a boost converter - then you won't lose any power in the converter. And while the router spec might say that it requires a 12V 1A supply you will probably find that it actually takes less power most of the time so you can get away with a smaller battery than you think.

Comment: For stationary batteries where weight is not an issue, lead acid will be cheaper and much easier to use than Lithium.

Comment: You are right that lead acid battery is a simple solution but it has huge volume + cost. I want to design a small system for it. What if I could add 2 LI-ION batteries in series and then boost 7V4 to 12V? I can get a good efficiency due to low deltaV.

Comment: Huge volume + cost? I'm not talking about a car battery, just the small ones you get in things like alarm panels. How small is your house? :)

Comment: Lithium ion will produce a more compact solution compared to lead acid. But lead acid is much cheaper than Lithium ion on a cost per Wh basis. Each 18650 cell (cylindrical laptop cell) is roughly 9 Wh, depending on specific cell. You could use 6 in series plus a buck converter. Or you could use a small lead acid battery. Due to shortcomings of lead acid, I would suggest using 100 Wh if you go that route. 100 Wh /12V = 8Ah, approximately. So an 8 Ah 12V lead battery. This would not be a large battery.

Comment: What Finbarr said is definitely true. The 12W rating may actually be the maximum, not the average. Average would normally be used for battery sizing calculations. So if you use 12W, you may get more than 3.5 hours of runtime.

Comment: Thanks finbarr and mkeith for your helpful suggestions. I would like to first check my router current(average) and would then try to use variable-power-supply to know its operating voltage range and cut-off voltage, because maybe it can operate lower than its specified voltage.

Comment: The datasheet of LI-ION state that the Max charging voltage is 4v2 so I can charge it at (4v2x6).Each cell has 2400mAH spec so six cells will have 6x2.4A=14.4A and I could fastly charge them at 1C, the total time it will take in fully charging (when they are almost low) will be ideally 14.4Ah/2.4A = 6Hours, right?
The other thing is; Typical voltage of LI-ION is 3v7 and its cut-of f discharge voltage is 2v75 so it would be better to design buck converter with (2v75x6) rather than (3v7x6) so that I can utilize most of the battery capacity. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

A small uninterruptable power supply can be made with a motorcycle or
automotive (or even a gel cell) 12V battery that will suit this need.  [PicoUPS at Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005TWE4GU)[PicoUPS](http://www.mini-box.com/picoUPS-100-12V-DC-micro-UPS-system-battery-backup-system).   The changeover when power fails is
automatic, as is the recovery when power returns.

More elaborate uninterruptible power supplies would also deliver AC
for other items (a telephone answering machine, for instance) while
delivering AC through the wall-wart to operate your router.

If you can get a power meter (Kill-a-Watt for instance), you may be surprised to find that your
router's nameplate power requirement is very conservative: it might only
take a fraction of the 12W that the adapter provides.   For this use,
the 'V-A' reading tells what the drain on a battery would be.

A battery alone will not handle the switchover, and will require charge
control, and won't give regulated output for your 12V appliance.  It
might work, but isn't ideal.